# Does a sigma algebra specifies a random variable?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

If we are given a random variable $X$, we call $\sigma(X)$ the sigma algebra generated by $X$

If I am given a sigma algebra $\mathcal F$,

1) when does exists a random variable $X$ such that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal F$?

2) when is this random variable "unique"? I don't care about "real" uniqueness but also something like "unique up to ad additive constant" or something like that

Thanks!

Comment: As long as the measure of the maximal member of the sigma algebra is 1, it will define a unique random variable, uniqueness given a.e.

Comment: @Paul Huh? Every random variable $Y=g(X)$ with $g$ invertible is such that $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X)$.

Comment: @Ant Maybe this is too formal for you but, given any $\mathcal F$ on $\Omega$, the function $X:(\Omega,2^\Omega)\to(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ defined by $X(\omega)=\omega$ for every $\omega$ is a random variable such that $\sigma(X)=\mathcal F$. Re 2., see my previous comment.

Comment: @Did, the question is to what extent Y and X would be considered unique here.  I don't see them being unique according to OP's ask.

Comment: @Paul There is no Y in the question. Your first comment seems to say that X is almost surely unique. Not so, by far.

Comment: @Did, I saw that.  What I am saying is that any other random variable Y such that $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X)$ is the "same" random variable (I know, "same" is loose concept, but this is close to what OP is thinking here).

Comment: @Paul Unless you explain "same", where is the information? And since the OP mentioned "unique up to a(n) additive constant", which is very far from working, one should first and foremost avoid to confirm them in this error.

Comment: @Did, fair enough.  I'd be interested in hearing from OP in how unique is unique.

Comment: Is the random variable $X$ with $\sigma(X)=\mathcal F$ to be real-valued?

Comment: @Paul This is fine! So $\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y)$  implies $Y = g(X)$ for some invertible function $g$? Also can you prove (or expand upon) your first statement? :-)

Comment: @JohnDawkins Not necessarily! Do things change ?

Comment: @Did Your example is clear, but I don't understand something; you just showed that every $\mathcal F$ can be generated by that $X$. So every random variable $Y$ such that $\sigma(Y)$ must be in the form $Y = g(X) = g(\omega)$ for invertible $g$ for what we said previously. But this would imply that all sigma algebras are generated by invertible functions which it's not true; so where did I go wrong?

Comment: "But this would imply that all sigma algebras are generated by invertible functions" Where did I say that? (And what does that mean exactly?)

Comment: @Did Well because any sigma algebra $\mathcal F$ is generated by something in the form $g(\omega)$ with $g$ invertible.. I came to using 1) Every $\mathcal F$ is generated by the $X$ you wrote and 2) If two random variables generate the same sigma algebra then one can be written as an (invertible)  function of one another